# <div> internal padding will not zero out

Tags: html, padding

I cannot remove the padding for a  that contains another . My site is www.housecallgeek.com/index.html. The div element has left and right margins that I cannot remove. source code is below

```
<style>


html{height:100%; background: url("http://www.housecallgeek.com/gdb.png") no-repeat center center fixed
; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

div.title{height:20%; width:100%; border-style:solid; border-width:0; margin:auto;


background: url("cropped merged finished smaller.png") no-repeat 49% 4% fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: 63%;
    -moz-background-size: 63%;
    -o-background-size: 63%;
    background-size: 63%;
}

body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; height: 100%;}

div.main{border:0px; margin:0px; padding:0px; width:80%; min-height:76%; border-style:solid; border-width:1;margin:auto;



background: url("md.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;

box-sizing: border-box;
ms-box-sizing: border-box;
webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

img.m{margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; width: 100%; height:100%;}

div.menu{margin:0px; padding:0px; min-width:100%; height:50px; display:box ;}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your image m.png seems to have transparent sides. try a clean crop of the image.

Comment: Yep, I'm assuming this is exactly what OP is referring to.